# URLConnection. Объясните, пожалуйста, доступно, что оно под собой подразумевает

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Люди добрые, объясните, пожалуйста, что подразумевает под собой UrlConnection. Что это класс понятно, но хотелось бы узнать, когда его нужно использовать и в каком случае.

Comment: что вы имеете в виду? вопрос задан слишком общо

Comment: Если ввести в гугле данный запрос, он выведет, что это класс, предназначенный для доступа к атрибутам удаленного ресурса. Понятно. Все методы мне тоже понятны, но я не понимаю, в каком случае нужно это использовать, то есть, когда я должна обратиться к данному классу. Насколько это полезно в использовании.

Comment: ОЧень полезно всегда, когда взаимодействуете с сервером. Почитайте про HTTP запросы ( https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP ) , этот класс используется для их реализации. Вы можете получать данные с сервера, отправлять их, изменять, удалять (последние три - если доступ позволяет). Этот класс может используется для создания любых приложений, взаимодействующих с интернетом.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, просто раньше писала как дерево, без этого коннекшена, поэтому новый термин ввел меня в заблуждение. Тогда еще вот такой вопрос, допустим я создаю новый url, мне нужно закинуть туда ссыль скажем, моего ресурса, у которого я собираюсь брать данные, отправлять и изменять, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например GET может выглядеть так

```
    public static String getHttpString(String s) {
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(s);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


          return content.toString();
    }
```

String s в данном случае это полный url, например http://www.example.com

Comment: Извините, не могу поднять вам репутацию в силу, отсутствия всяких трофеев на своем профиле, но спасибо вам большое за терпение и ответы!

Comment: Не за что, я ничего такого сложного не сделал :) Я советую внимательнее почитать про классы UrlConnection и HttpUrlConnection, это есть в книге Java 7. Полное руководство Герберта Шилдта, саму книгу реально найти в интернете, я находил :) Там больше информации, чем я Вам дал, да и докумнтация от Oracle по классу тоже может послужить хорошей поддержкой, когда поймете, что это за метод и где его применять.